# Clone Mercurial repository of Eclipse workspace and rebuild in another place

Tags: c, eclipse, mercurial

I work on a Eclipse workspace, then I clone the workplace to a backup repository, I want to continue to code and build it without any setting changed in Eclipse in the backup repository.

```
hg clone Eclipse-workspace Eclipse-backup-repo
```

File structure of `Eclipse-workspace`

```
+- Eclipse-workspace
   +- api-project
      +- Debug
      +- Release
      +- src
         +- api.c
      +- inc
         +- api.h
   +- project2
      +- Debug
      +- Release
      +- src
         + main.c
```

The cloned file structure of `Eclipse-backup-repo`

```
+- Eclipse-backup-repo
   +- api-project
      +- src
         +- api.c
      +- inc
         +- api.h
   +- project2
      +- src
         + main.c
```

This is my .hgignore

```
# use glob syntax. syntax: glob

.metadata/** 
Debug/** 
Release/**
.settings/** 
.cproject 
.project 
.hgignore

# switch to regexp syntax.

syntax: regexp
```

Is it possible? How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Import Wizard to  command link import an existing project into workspace.

1. From the main menu bar, select  command link File > Import.... The Import wizard opens.
2. Select General > Existing Project into Workspace and click Next.
3. Choose either Select root directory or Select archive file and click the associated Browse to locate the directory or file containing the projects.
4. Under Projects select the project or projects which you would like to import.
5. Click Finish to start the import.

It works for me.

[Importing existing projects](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm)